# Lucene .pos files size

Tags: lucene

I tried to index about 600mb files with Lucene 4.10 (parsing them with TIKA and indexing). Everything works fine, but I noticed that .pos file is more than 1GB that looks very suspicious to me, is there any way to reduce size of .pos file or to disable it at all ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50PostingsFormat.html

the `.pos` file are the term positions that are needed to search for multiple words in an exact order like "stack overflow".

You can disable their creation by setting it on the `FieldFormat` with `setStoreTermVectorPositions(false)`: 
https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html

1GB of positions sounds a lot, it isn't normally this big. In my case the .pos file is about 10% of the index size, with positions enabled on all text fields.

Comment: Thanks, strange, in my case looks like .pos file is the biggest within the index files, it's significant bigger, and it's about 90% of the index size, maybe it's because of relatively old version of Lucene (4.10.4) ? If I'll disable this, then it can find "overflow stack" and "stack blah overflow", or second is not relevant ?

Comment: It will find all pages that contain "stack" and "overflow" somewhere, but they might not be even in the same paragraph. This produces results that are a lot less relevant to the query.